# Unable to open bootstrap modal based on some demonstrations

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to learn how to use the bootstrap model.  I tried to follow the documentation and some youtube videos and this is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body>
      <button type="button" class="form-text term" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#termsModal">Open Modal</button>
      <div class="modal fade" id="termsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="termsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="termsModalLabel">Terms of Use</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Okay</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I click the `Open Modal` button, nothing happens.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [Bootstrap 5 migration docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#javascript), the `data-` attributes have changed to `data-bs-` in Bootstrap 5.

> "Data attributes for all JavaScript plugins are now namespaced to help
> distinguish Bootstrap functionality from third parties and your own
> code. For example, we use data-bs-toggle instead of data-toggle."